# Designing Asynchronous Digital Circuit

Tags: digital-logic

Following through an example of designing an asynchronous circuit, Im stuck working out the state diagram. The design brief is:

> Design a circuit that has an input w and output z where z is ‘0’ if the number of previously applied pulses is even and z is ‘1’ if the number of previously applied pulses is odd.

The state diagram in the example looks like: 
[image: State Diagram]

But I don't see how this matches to the design brief, because I don't understand how it know whether the last set of pulses were odd or even. So how is this the case?

Comment: I would implement this as a pair of T-Flip-Flops, one on the rising edge and one on the falling edge of the input.  This would give me a 2-bit state variable.  An xor-gate would take the state variable and convert it into the output signal.  You didn't ask how to implement this, which is why I put this in a comment.  Even so, I thought it was interesting enough to share.

Comment: @DavidKessner Don't T flip flops require a clock? Then its not asynchronous design.

Comment: The input to the state machine goes into the TFF clock input.  Make the TFFs out of gates and nobody will be the wiser.  I am also using a simple TFF.  Just a "clk" in and an output that toggles on a clk edge.

Comment: Dont need a pair of T FF and a counter with a clock may be sync or async.  The simplest case is an async counter or T FF David a clock does not define if a counter is synchronus although FF's commonkly used in both async operations or sync with other operations.. it is irrelevant here

Comment: One wouldn't wish to do that, other than for homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is reset into state A (which is not shown on the state diagram), after an odd number of rising edges on its input, it will be in state B or C, after an even number it will be in states D or A. So, the current state implies the knowledge (B or C implies odd number, D or A implies even) and the output signal makes that knowledge explicit).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, its detecting for a change at the input. How did I not see this before.

Answer (score 0):

let me exaplin how to read I read the State Diagram.. If you use mapping reduction methods, you notice all changes occur on rising edge or active high async operations.

Now teaching how to read a State Diagram is like teaching how to read a schematic.

1. At initial state A output =0 and stays there until input = one (1)  to arrive at state B
2. State B is still out = 0 while it waits for input to go high again and when it does  resets the output = 0  ( swallows an even pulse)
3. State C occurs when input goes low and removes the previous set condition in an internal latch waiting for input to go high to state D
4. State D Sets output high upon the rising edge of input. (another odd event high state)
5. State D removed the Set latch condition with an internal memory state and is waiting for Rest from aanother input low to high transition then Resets output Low and moves back to State A
6. State A also removes the Reset internal state while it sets the output.

Since there are 4 States then two latches are required to count the phases using  set/reset internal inputs.  The 3rd  RS FF is used to define the ouput on every 2nd state using Set Reset gating...

All together you have  1 D Flip flop with Qbar to D using Clk as the active input that detects the State diagram changes of inputs from O to 1... in other words rising edge sensitive.

[image]

Given the requirement to count the odd pulse  ( or ever other pulse) you have a simple divide by two counter. Only the initial conditions determine if you start with zero or one. When you reset to zero.. the complementary output is detected to toggle or count the 1st pulse and thereafter ignore every even pulse after that.. thus a divide by two.

A simple T FF or D FF with negative feedback or /2 counter is all that is needed.